# Combobox or Listbox?

Tags: c#, combobox, listbox

I was curious if I should use a listbox or combobox to look up warehouse part numbers and then fire an event if it is clicked. I want to be able to click that number and then send a specific command out a serial port. I currently use a selection of hyperlinks to do this but there are now to many and a dropdown list would be helpful to select from and fire the same command as if it was the hyperlink.

Here is my code for when a hyperlink is clicked for part HC1_101... could I replace this with a listbox to send the same command? Can I just add the links to the dropdown list?

```
private void linkLabel_HC1_101_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
    {
        var content = new List<byte>();
        content.Add(2);
        content.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("01P00101##"));
        content.Add(3);
        byte[] buffer = content.ToArray();
        serialPort1.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many developers would normally use a DropDownList control. Each item in the list has both a `Text` property (what the user sees on the screen) and a `Value` property (which is only seen by your code). Here is a sample:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="MyDropDownList" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="MyDropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
   <asp:ListItem Value="1">Item One</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="2">Item Two</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="3">Item Three</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The text and values in the ListItems can be constructed by your code or from a datasource. And in your server code you have something like this to handle the user making a selection from the list:

```
    protected void MyDropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string value;

        value = MyDropDownList.SelectedValue;

        // TBD: Construct content from the value, and send it to your serial port.
    }
```

Does this help?